# Instagram api V1 suddenly all limits dropped

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I am a new user and we have Api V1. We've been using it since 2 months.

From yesterday we started having an issue with our limits. They suddenly dropped to the limits of unsigned calls.

Today we added SIG, changed this in our Code and also checked the Enforce Signed Requests button (we did not have this update before)

We are able to send the requests now and they look like signed but limits are still 20 relations per hour (like for unsigned calls)

I emailed Instagram team but there is no answer yet.

I am just not sure what to do. Whether we can use it or if we should wait or do something else.

I would really appreciate any advice on this issue. Here's our code.

```
/** * Sign header by using the app's IP and its API secret. 
  * * @return string The signed header 
*/ 
private function _getSignature($endpoint, $params) 
{ 
  $secret = $this->_apisecret; 
  $params['access_token'] = $this->getAccessToken(); 
  $sig = $endpoint; ksort($params); 

  foreach ($params as $key => $val) 
  { 
    $sig .= "|$key=$val"; 
  } 

  return hash_hmac('sha256', $sig, $secret, false); }
```

Comment: Please share some code

Comment: @Korpel I have it now but can't paste here as it's too long...let me try

Comment: @Korpel It looks like all requests are being sent fine meaning that we do not receive "Invalid parameter sig" but still having limits like unsigned calls

Answer (score 0):

Instagram no longer supports signed "header", you have to implement secure API calls to get the higher limits

You must have missed this email from Instagram:

> When we announced our publishing guidelines for likes/relationship
>   actions, we also introduced a new technique to sign API requests. As
>   part of this announcement we set a deprecation date for the previous
>   signed-headers functionality to Sept 1, 2015.
>
> This email is to let you know that support for signed-headers has now
>   been deprecated. We know that a number of developers (including your
>   company) are still relying on this option, and have whitelisted your
>   client_id for an extended period. Please plan the migration to
>   securing your application with signed-requests as soon as possible.
>   You can learn more about this feature here:
>   https://instagram.com/developer/secure-api-requests/.
>
> The extended support will end on Nov 1 2015. You will see your
>   rate-limits for publishing likes/follows/comments reduced if you
>   haven’t migrated after this date.

Comment: ! Thank you so much for the info! We have missed the date apparently and all limits dropped on the 1th of Nov as they stated. Do you know what shall I do now? Email the Instagram  support again? Do you think revoking app token from user panel can help? I saw this advice somewhere. Thank you!!!

Comment: Just to clarify that we have implemented secure API calls but we did not get the higher limits

Comment: have you checked the "secure API" option in the instagram->manage clients for your app ?

Comment: Yes!!! we have!! Have a look at the screenshot here please :) http://joxi.ru/Q2Kn7R3TXJX8mj